Calculate the value of an angle in JavaScript
Im trying to make a code that calculates the value of an angle in a right angle triangle provided its sin, cos or tan. For example, in a calculator, if you have the value of sin(x) and you want to find the angle you input sin^-1(x) and get said angle. How can I make this code in JavaScript?
I tried using this code but it didnt work and I dont know if it helps me in my project:


radianToDegree = r => r * 180 * Math.PI ** -1
console.log(radianToDegree(Math.asin(0.5)).toFixed(3) * 1)




"it didnt work". Please elaborate further. What doesn't work and what did you expect to happen? See How to Ask and its linked resources for more info.

Are you asking about the math to perform this calculation, or do you already know the math and are you asking about a problem in your implementation?  Please clarify.

To calculate the angle of a right triangle when given its sine, cosine, or tangent value in JavaScript, you can use the inverse trigonometric functions (Math.asin(), Math.acos(), Math.atan()). These functions return the angle in radians, but you can easily convert it to degrees by multiplying the result by (180 / Math.PI).
Here is an example of how you can do this:
function calculateAngle(value, ratioType) {
    let angleInRadians;

    // Determine which inverse trig function to use
    if (ratioType === "sin") {
        angleInRadians = Math.asin(value);
    } else if (ratioType === "cos") {
        angleInRadians = Math.acos(value);
    } else if (ratioType === "tan") {
        angleInRadians = Math.atan(value);
    } else {
        throw new Error("Invalid ratio type. Use 'sin', 'cos', or 'tan'.");
    }

    // Convert radians to degrees
    const angleInDegrees = angleInRadians * (180 / Math.PI);

    return angleInDegrees;
}

// Examples:
console.log(calculateAngle(0.5, "sin")); // Output: 30
console.log(calculateAngle(0.5, "cos")); // Output: 60
console.log(calculateAngle(1, "tan"));   // Output: 45


I downvoted this answer, because it's not helpful. The OP already uses Math.asin and 180 * Math.PI ** -1 in the question, and the code int the question correctly prints 30.

What does OP mean?

The original post or original poster.
